# How can I highlight multiple lines in gVim without using the mouse?

Tags: vim

Vim noob here. I am trying to select multiple lines of code to copy and paste in other areas. Is there a way to do this without using the mouse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few other ways that don't use visual mode at all:

**using marks**

1. leave a mark somewhere with `ma`
2. move somewhere else
3. yank from here to there with `y'a`

**using search motions**

1. localize some unique token at the end of the part you want to yank
2. yank from here to there with `y/foo<cr>` (forward search) or `y?bar<cr>` (backward search)

**using text-objects**

1. determine what text-object would map to what you want to yank:

   - inner/outer word, `iw`/`aw`
   - inner/outer pair, `i'"([{<`/`a'"([{<`
   - inner/outer html tag, `it`/`at`
   - sentence, `s`
   - paragraph, `p`
   - "block", `]`
   - …
2. yank that text-object with, say, `yip`

**using other motions**

- yank to end of function: `y]}`
- yank to end of file: `yG`

**all of the above solutions with visual mode**

- `V'ay`
- `V/foo<cr>y`
- `V?bar<cr>y`
- `Vipy`, etc.
- `V]}y`
- `VGy`

---

`:h motion.txt` will hopefully blow your mind, like it did to mine.

Comment: thank you. I see that you create 'sentences' with multiple commands. I am also trying to learn how to think and utilize them. Is there a resource I can find that teaches people how to use Vim like that? Thanks again!

Comment: There are a few "vim grammar" blog posts that popped up recently, they are a quick google away… Basically using Vim is like speaking a language: you have "actions" (yank,paste,delete, etc.), "objects" on which to perform the actions (current word, from here to EOL, current paragraph, etc.) and "modifiers" that you can use to perform an action multiple times or on multiple targets or the nth target, etc. You compose these building blocks *exactly* like you'd think, write or speak. That's the most awesome and efficient way to edit text.

Comment: Most of it is in `$ vimtutor`. If you skipped this step, you owe it to yourself to go through it. Right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can place your cursor in the first line you want to copy and then type `nyy` where `n` is the number of lines you want to copy. For example, type `2yy` to copy the two lines under the cursor.

Then, you can paste them using `p`.

You can also select multiple lines by placing your cursor somewhere and keeping Shift pressed. Move your cursor to the end of the desired selection and stop pressing Shift. Then copy using just `y` (and not `yy`) and paste with `p`.

Comment: ah... i forgot about the thing that made vim... vim.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, in normal mode type `V[direction]` and you will highlight multiple lines. If you don't want whole lines, use `v` instead of `V`. To copy it, hit `y` and move to the area which you want to paste in and hit `p`. To delete it, instead of `y` use `x`.

Alternatively, you can simply use `[number of lines]yy` to yank some number of lines or `[number of lines]dd` to cut some number of lines. In this case pasting is the same.